# Why does sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file require an explicit cast on datetime2 column?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, sql-server-2022

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#table-returned) the returned column `timestamp_utc` should be of type *datetime2(7)*

But when I query like this

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('system_health*.xel', null, null, null)
WHERE timestamp_utc > dateadd(hour, -1, GETUTCDATE())
```

It returns no rows. It returns the rows only when I add an explicit cast to *datetime2*

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('system_health*.xel', null, null, null)
WHERE cast(timestamp_utc as datetime2(7)) > dateadd(hour, -1, GETUTCDATE())
```

Which matches the [last example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-retrieving-data-from-file-targets) in the documentation (even though no attention is drawn to it)

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Erland Sommarskog asked me about this in May 2022.

It's a bug exposed when a predicate is pushed down into the internal streaming table-valued function. The return type is indeed `datetime2(7)` but the source is a Windows `FILETIME`.

The predicate is pushed down below the internal conversion, so the server ends up trying to compare a `datetime2` with a `FILETIME`, which does not work.

[image: Pushed down predicate]
<sub>*Pushed down predicate*</sub>

When you add the explicit conversion, the predicate can no longer be pushed into the TVF so it appears as a separate Filter:

[image: Separate Filter]
<sub>*Predicate evaluated in a separate filter*</sub>

I have no idea why this hasn't been fixed.

Erland subsequently created a feedback item: [Filtering output from fn_xe_file_target_read_file on timestamp_utc returns no rows](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5f8e52d6-f3d2-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9)